# ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and referential integrity

Tags: asp.net, mysql, active-directory, asp.net-membership, referential-integrity

In the past, when I implemented my own authentication mechanisms I would have a user table with relationships to other tables in my application's MySQL database.  However, now that I'm considering using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, I see no way to create similar relationships between AD users and those tables.

What's the normal way to resolve this issue?  Should I just accept the fact that someone could potentially insert records with user IDs that don't correspond to existing users?  I don't realistically expect this to happen, but I'm used to ensuring integrity at the database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to give up on database referential integrity in this case. Just have your application code check for the existence of the Active Directory account before adding the record to the DB.

In theory, some user could go in manually and type a SQL INSERT statement which refers to an invalid AD account. But in practice, hopefully you aren't giving a bunch of users direct table access. If the application code is the only thing accessing the DB, the application code is validating the account before inserting the row, and that validation code is tested, then you should be OK.

Just to be safe, you could have a nightly batch process that validates all rows in your referencing table(s) against Active Directory. If it finds any inconsistency, it can send you an email. This won't prevent integrity violations, but at least it will let you know about them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway you could do this via MySQL.  If you were using SQL server, you could write a trigger that would call a C# dll that would verify that they were an AD member.  Then if they weren't you could block the insertion into the DB.  You might be able to do something like this with MySQL, but my knowledge of MySQL is pretty slim.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Probably somewhat overkill for my scenario, though.  I'm mainly wondering what other people who use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider do about this, if anything.